# Kitematic: connecting to a docker machine with different name

Tags: node.js, docker, virtual-machine, boot2docker, dockerfile

How does one connect to a docker machine with a different name (other then default). It seems its only possible to use the docker machine that Kinematic launches on boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently on their to do list https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/1005 and https://github.com/docker/kitematic/pull/992

So at the moment it isn't possible from Kitematic.

You can do much more with [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) but the trade-off is that it is a command-line interface

Comment: I just wanted to use it to see an uncluttered log from specific containers. back to the command-line!